# Using Forward- ,Backward Automatic Differentiation to compute higher order derivatives

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, automatic-differentiation

Im currently trying to wrap my head around Automatic Differentiation. I got to the point where i
successfully implemented both forward and reverse mode autodiff. Now to my question:

Given a function **f** i want to compute the **second derivative**. How to
compose forward and reverse mode to achive this. My current understanding is, that you first run
one pass of forward-mode and then run the reverse-mode ontop of this pass but this doesnt yield the
excpected results.

help would be very appreciated, have a nice day :)

Comment: Is this question relevant to SO? Maybe post on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i guess if theres an automatic-differentiation tag than probably yes

Comment: but wouldnt hurt to post it theres thanks!